# How to rename file in c# when uploading?

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I am developing one application in web api and angularjs. I have file upload part. I am able to upload files and i am not storing files in webroot(i created folder called Uploads). My problem is i am not using any good naming convention to maintain uniqueness of files so there are chances of overriding files. I am new to angularjs so i refered below link. `http://instinctcoder.com/angularjs-upload-multiple-files-to-asp-net-web-api/` 
This is my controller level code.

```
if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
{
    throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
}
var uploadPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Uploads");
var multipartFormDataStreamProvider = new CustomUploadMultipartFormProvider(uploadPath);
await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(multipartFormDataStreamProvider);
var fileName = "";
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
foreach (var key in multipartFormDataStreamProvider.Contents)
{
    var a = key.Headers;
    fileName = a.ContentDisposition.FileName;
    break;
}
foreach (var key in multipartFormDataStreamProvider.FormData.AllKeys)
{
    foreach (var val in multipartFormDataStreamProvider.FormData.GetValues(key))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", key, val));
    }
}
```

In the above code I am trying to add date part to beginning of file name as below

```
string filenameNew = "App1" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
fileName = filenameNew + a.ContentDisposition.FileName; 

public CustomUploadMultipartFormProvider(string path) : base(path) { }
public override string GetLocalFileName(HttpContentHeaders headers)
{
    string startwith = "Nor" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
    if (headers != null && headers.ContentDisposition != null)
    {
        return headers
            .ContentDisposition
            .FileName.TrimEnd('"').TrimStart('"').StartsWith("startwith").ToString();
    }
    return base.GetLocalFileName(headers);
}
```

This i tried but whatever the original file name that only comes. May I get some idea where can i append datepart to file while saving? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I'm assuming that `CustomUploadMultipartFormProvider` writes to the filename given in the `ContentDisposition` header, and your `filename` variable is just reading this value. Maybe not an exact answer to your question, but you could probably just rename the file after its been uploaded.

Comment: Yep, at the point this request occurs, the files have already been written.  Notice no where in this code are you actually performing any file writes, because the files already exist in `uploadPath`.  You'd need to either simply perform a filesystem rename, or use a different upload technique that provides you the stream as it's being uploaded.

Comment: Thank you. i updated my code. But that is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do inside of the `GetLocalFileName`, this is pretty messed up.

First off, `StartsWith` returns a boolean (true or false) that indicates if the string *starts with* whatever you put in the parenthesis.

```
string str = "SIMPLE";
bool t = str.StartsWith("SIM"); // true
bool f = str.StartsWith("ZIM"); // false
```

The fact you're turning this bool back into a string and also passing the string `"startsWith"` into the method, means it will **always** return the string `"false"` (a bool value converted into a string) unless the real filename starts with `"startsWith"`.

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
public override string GetLocalFileName(HttpContentHeaders headers)
{
    string prefix = "Nor" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
    if (headers != null && headers.ContentDisposition != null)
    {
        var filename = headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Trim('"');
        return prefix + filename;
    }
    return base.GetLocalFileName(headers);
}
```

My suggestion for you is to learn the basics of C# and .Net a bit more, maybe read a C# book or something.